# SharePoint list permissions to stop users from editing list items once created

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, item-level-permissions, sharepoint-permissions

I am working on a SharePoint portal for an organization which utilizes the Lists of SharePoint to store data related to the students and the classes they are enrolled in.
The portal also contains lists that stores the reviews of the performance of the students which are submitted or added in the lists by the class instructors via a HTML form added to a site page.

The data being sensitive in nature to the organization, the organization wants it to be immutable or in other words the instructors can only create or add it in the list and not be able to remove or edit it, once it's been created in list.

I was able to make sure that the instructors can only edit list items which were created by them and not of any other, but the organization wants to even remove this permission as well and wants the instructors to only add the data in the list but not be able to edit it once added in the list.

Is there any work around this can be achieved in the SharePoint?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge: No, you cannot protect an item from being modified by its creator.

However, there are means to deal with that. One method might be to change the ownership of an item, I read about different ways using EventHandler or Powershell tricks. But I cannot replicate them thorouhgly.

Nowadays I recommend using MS Flow, as a Flow is easy to set up and is relatively flexibly to use.

Basically I think of the following way:

- Trigger on the "creation of a SP list element"
- Add a new item with all fields set to the original one. "create item"
- Delete the original item. "Delete item"

The copy will have the creator of the flow (e.g. you) as owner and that will prevent others from editing it, if the list settings are set accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the creator, there may be no way to prevent him from accessing the data.But for visitors,you can try to add a permission level with only add permission to test.